# dc.js Scatter Plot and elasticY behavior

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

Should elasticY(true) enable the Scatter Plot to recalculate the y axis range whenever a redraw event is triggered?

I have used the Scatter Brushing example to demonstrate.  The following attributes were added to each chart:

```
.yAxisPadding('5%')  // Allow the max values to be brushed
.elasticY(true)      // Allow the chart to recalculate the Y axis range
```

Here is a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/woolycew65/w58rvdsx/) example.

I thought by brushing the left scatter plot, selecting a couples of dots in the middle of the chart, would cause the right scatter plot to recalculate its Y axis range.  But that does not seem to be correct.  Is it a bug or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As always with `elasticX` and `elasticY`, dc.js is looking at all of the bins, whether or not they are empty.

You could argue that it is faithfully displaying all the data, it just happens that some of that data is zeroes. :-)

To remove those zeroes, use `remove_empty_bins` from the FAQ:

```
    function remove_empty_bins(source_group) {
        return {
            all: function () {
                return source_group.all().filter(function(d) {
                    //return Math.abs(d.value) > 0.00001; // if using floating-point numbers
                    return d.value !== 0; // if integers only
                });
            }
        };
    }
    chart1
        .group(remove_empty_bins(group1))
    chart2
        .group(remove_empty_bins(group2))
```

[Fork of your fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/ajfqqke7/1/)

Note that the scatter plot [joins the data in a naive way](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/1153) which doesn't provide very good animated transitions. I generally advise just turning off the transitions for scatter plots with `.transitionDuration(0)` because they are not useful.

Comment: An related question to elasticY can be found [ElasticY bound by BrushY values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079293/dc-js-elasticy-range-bound-by-brush-y-values)