# dc.js elasticY range bound by brush y values

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

How can we control the elasticY recalculation of the Y axis range, on a scatter plot, to be bound by the brushes Y range?  Thus if a scatter plot has a brush bounded on the Y axis between [6-8) and the elasticY recalculates the new Y axis range to be [3-7] we would like the new Y axis range to be [3-8], because if it used 7 the top part of the brush would be off the screen.

```
.elasticY(true)
```

[A jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/ajfqqke7/1/).

1. Brush the 1st scatter plot x=8, y=[6,9) "Around the two dots".  Everything looks good.
2. Brush the 2nd scatter plot y=8, z=12 (Around the single dot).  The brush on scatter plot #1 is out of bounds.

We would like to restrict the Y axis on scatter plot #1 so the brush is still in bounds.  Is there a straight forward way to do this or an override?

Actually our scatterPlots only use a yAxis brush.

[image]

Comment: I started to look into this but ran into some weird feedback issues because the brush can affect the scale of its own diagram, and the other diagram, and back again. [Very confusing](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/ajfqqke7/8/)!

Comment: Does that mean you are waving the white flag?  I will take a look at your jsfiddle code to see where you were going, but I am at a 3rd grade level compared to your PhD.

Comment: Not giving up! Just ran out of time for the moment. I think it's really a good idea but these feedback loops are always tricky. You don't really want any chart to affect its own view, and it's even worse when two charts start affecting each other recursively.

Comment: This is working for our scatterPlots that are only using a yAxis brush,  but it would be interesting to incorporate into the base to work with the current default scatterPlot brush (x and y).